# How to Show Parameters Create Component vb.net

Tags: vb.net, components

I created a component and would like options to appear in the options and not numbers.
Can someone help me?

Original
TextBox.Align = Left / Right / Center
[Original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6cxJ.png)

My component
TextMix.Align = 0/1/2
[MyControl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5h6G.png)

How to display "Left, Right or Center" and not "0, 1 or 2"?

```
Public Shadows Property TextAlign() As String
    Get
        TextAlign = sxTexto.TextAlign
    End Get
    Set(ByVal Value As String)
        sxTexto.TextAlign = Value
    End Set
End Property
```

Comment: Rather than string use `System.Windows.Forms.HorizontalAlignment` as the type or `System.Drawing.ContentAlignment` to use the set from Label

Comment: Did you read the documentation to check the type of that `TextAlign` property of the `TextBox` class?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We are not a coders-for-hire service. Please explain what you have tried so far and why it hasn't worked.